# Laravel Request getting current path with query string

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-request

Is there a Laravel way to get the current path of a Request with its query parameters?

For instance, for the URL:

```
http://www.example.com/one/two?key=value
```

`Request::getPathInfo()` would return `/one/two`.

`Request::url()` would return `http://www.example.com/one/two`.

The desired output is `/one/two?key=value`.

Answer (score 129, accepted):

Try to use the following:

```
\Request::getRequestUri()
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. It returns exactly what OP wants. Works fine on 5.2.

Comment: Still working on Laravel 9. Alternative syntax using the helper: `request()->getRequestUri()`.

Comment: Would this work to just get that one value from the key param?
`request()->get('key')`

Answer (score 66):

### Laravel 4.5

Just use

```
Request::fullUrl()
```

It will return the full url

You can extract the Querystring with str_replace

```
str_replace(Request::url(), '', Request::fullUrl())
```

Or you can get a array of all the queries with

```
Request::query()
```

### Laravel >5.1

Just use

```
$request->fullUrl()
```

It will return the full url

You can extract the Querystring with str_replace

```
str_replace($request->url(), '',$request->fullUrl())
```

Or you can get a array of all the queries with

```
$request->query()
```

Comment: in newer versions of laravel use `$request` instance instead of statically calling the function of Request

Comment: in my case, I wanted the query parameter order to be preserved, but `fullUrl ` mysteriously changes the order of my parameter. 

i had to resort in pure php then
$actual_link = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? "https" : "http") . "://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";

Comment: `Request::fullUrl()` worked perfectly on Laravel 4.

Comment: `$request->query()` awesome in 5.4

Answer (score 41):

**Request** class doesn't offer a method that would return exactly what you need. But you can easily get it by concatenating results of 2 other methods:

```
echo (Request::getPathInfo() . (Request::getQueryString() ? ('?' . Request::getQueryString()) : '');
```

Comment: Yeah, there are tons of ways otherwise: `str_replace(url(), '', Request::fullUrl())`

Comment: `request()->getQueryString()` has the added benefit of being available in the blade without any odd include's or variables being passed in if you need to alter url's in the content.

Comment: Actually there is a method that returns exactly the full URL... The [answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35130810/1090395) works in Laravel 5 also

Answer (score 14):

Get the current URL including the query string.

```
echo url()->full();
```

Comment: if you'll have dots in query they will become underscores e.g. `nested.foo=bar` => `nested_foo=bar`, `\Request::getRequestUri()` gives exact results

Answer (score 5):

If you have access to the `Request $request` object you can also use the non static method

```php
$request->getRequestUri()
```

Answer (score 2):

`$request->fullUrl()` will also work if you are injecting `Illumitate\Http\Request`.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest I found is this one:

```php
$request->getPathInfo()
```

Comment: The question was about getting the full path including the query string. The question already mentions that the `getPathInfo()` method did not work for this.

Answer (score 1):

This worked in laravel 9 for me:

```
$request()->getRequestUri()
```

Comment: Hi, there is already this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67586325/7353417). Also, you are missing `$`

Answer (score 0):

```
public functin func_name(Request $request){$reqOutput = $request->getRequestUri();}
```

Answer (score -1):

Get the flag parameter from the URL string
http://cube.wisercapital.com/hf/create?flag=1

```
public function create(Request $request)
{
$flag = $request->input('flag');
return view('hf.create', compact('page_title', 'page_description', 'flag'));
}
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.